# How to show that $ \forall x\in \Bbb R, |x|=x $ is false?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Condersider the statement $ \forall x\in \Bbb R, |x|=x $

I know this statement is false, so to prove this, I need to prove this by contradiction that $\exists x \in \Bbb R$ such that $|x|\neq x $.

So, can I just prove this by: 
 $\exists -x \in \Bbb R$ such that $|-x|=x $ by definition of the absolute value?

Comment: I have changed the initial tag : this question is not about discrete mathematics, but about logic for "continuous mathematics."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x=-1$, 
$$|-1|=1 \neq -1$$

Hence the statement is false.

Comment: @Lily: What he did was provide what is known as a "counterexample"--that is, an example that shows a universal claim (like $\forall x\in\Bbb R, |x|=x$) is not true. He showed, by example, that $\exists x\in\Bbb R:|x|\neq x.$ In particular, $x=-1$ satisfies this.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Let $x$ be $0$. Then $|x|=x$ but it proves your statement that

$$ \exists -x\in \mathbb{R} : |-x| = x $$

It doesn't prove that the statement is false. You should find an $x$ that isn't equal to its absolute value (a negative number, like $-1$...)